# Working titles of Star Wars films?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, production

I learned from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112580/what-is-the-origin-of-blue-harvest) that *Blue Harvest* was the working title of Star Wars Episode VI (*Return of the Jedi*), and it made me wonder: did any of the other Star Wars films have similarly surprising working titles?

### What were the working titles of the seven Star Wars films to date?

And what are the working titles, if any, of the planned eighth and ninth?

<sub><sup>Please include sources for your answers.</sup></sub>

Comment: "Blue Harvest" was a deceptive "cover title" to keep nosy Star Wars fans off production sites. That's not the usual meaning of "working title", which is what you call a project internally before choosing a final name.

Comment: Also, Episode VI was called _**Revenge** of the Jedi_ before George Lucas realised that revenge was an emotion Jedi should be above, so he settled on _Return of the Jedi_. Promotional material exists with the older title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Episode I:  *The Beginning*

*Star Wars:  Episode I:  The Phantom Menace* used the working title [*The Beginning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_%E2%80%93_The_Phantom_Menace)

---

### Episode II:  *Jar- Jar's Big/Great Adventure*

*Star Wars:  Episode II:  Attack of the Clones* used the working title [*Jar-Jar's Big Adventure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_II_%E2%80%93_Attack_of_the_Clones) or [*Jar-Jar's Great Adventure*](http://starwarz.com/starkiller/episodeii/).

> As an in-joke, the film's working title was Jar Jar's Big Adventure, a sarcastic reference to the negative fan response to the Episode I character.
>   -  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_II_%E2%80%93_Attack_of_the_Clones)

---

### Episodes III, IV, and V:  No working titles

*Star Wars:  Episode III:  Revenge of the Sith*, *Star Wars:  Episode IV:  A New Hope* and *Episode V:  The Empire Strikes Back* don't seem to have had working titles while in production.

However, the early drafts of the script for Episode IV went by many names, including [*The Adventures of Luke Starkiller As Taken From the Journal of the Whills*.](http://starwarz.com/starkiller/star-wars-the-adventures-of-luke-starkiller-as-taken-from-the-journal-of-the-whills/)

---

### Episode VI:  *Blue Harvest*

*Star Wars:  Episode VI:  Return of the Jedi* used the working title [*Blue Harvest*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112580/what-is-the-origin-of-blue-harvest)

[image]

> Famously, Return of the Jedi was made under the title ‘Blue Harvest’, while the prequel trilogy was made under the name 'JAK Productions'.
>   -  [The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/star-wars-8-secret-working-title-has-supposedly-been-revealed-a6823261.html)

---

### Episode VII:  *Foodles*

*Star Wars:  Episode VII:  The Force Awakens* apparently shared its working title with Abrams' production company:  [*Foodles*](http://www.ibtimes.com.au/star-wars-episode-viii-working-title-revealed-force-awakens-comics-adaptation-announced-1505553)

> “Star Wars: The Force Awakens” had “Foodles” as a working title.
>   -  [IB Times](http://www.ibtimes.com.au/star-wars-episode-viii-working-title-revealed-force-awakens-comics-adaptation-announced-1505553)

---

### Episode VIII:  *Space Bear*

*Star Wars:  Episode VIII* seems to be using the working title *Space Bear:  Episode VIII*, [according to Carrie Fisher](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/star-wars-8-title-revealed-by-carrie-fisher-how-space-bear-related-force-awakens-1545207) and [Mark Hamill](http://comicbook.com/2016/02/24/mark-hamill-tweets-exotic-creature-picture-from-star-wars-episod/).  The logo appears to include a picture of a panda.

[image]

> The actress, who portrays the iconic character of Princess Leia, shared a picture of pet dog Gary resting on her on-set chair which bore the movie's tentative title "Space Bear: Episode VIII."
>   - [IB Times](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/star-wars-8-title-revealed-by-carrie-fisher-how-space-bear-related-force-awakens-1545207)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it me, or does anyone else think the bottommost photo looks shopped?

Comment: Wait, you forgot the most famous working title of all, for _A New Hope_.  At the time of filming, it was never referred to as _A New Hope_...